# Smart App Banner in Facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, mobile, twitter

When a user opens a link in their Facebook iPhone app to our page, how do you get the Smart App Banner to show at the top of the page? It doesn't show I'm assuming because the Apple Dev site says Smart App Banners don't show up in frames. Is there a way around this? Do I have to build my own custom banner?

This is also an issue in Twitter. Our app shares links to FB and Twitter back to our site. I'm trying to figure out how to make the Smart App Banner to show up whether viewing in iPhone Safari, Facebook, or Twitter.

Answer (score 2):

Smart App Banners require a meta tag in the header of the page.  They cannot be used in frames.  So without access to the source code of Facebook and Twitter, this isn't possible.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to build your own smart banner or use someones work. I had the same problem and would like the visitors to our website to find our app using a "smart banner".

I have adapted this great script: https://github.com/ijason

Had to make a few changes to link to the app in App Store instead of the artist e.g. changed the code artistViewUrl to trackViewUrl = json.results[0].trackViewUrl to link directly to the app instead of the developer in my case.

It's implemented  here and has been tested it in Messenger, Twitter and the native Facebook app. The usual smart banner  is shown in Safari. The other will appear in other browsers and when using frames.

https://eventsane.com/Events/United-States/New-York/New-York-City

So far it has given the result I was aiming for even though Facebook steals the best spot in the Messenger app. Hope it helps.

[image: Messenger with customized smart banner]